# Sitecore sitemap.xml for multisite implementation

Tags: sitemap

Currently we have a single site on the website and the sitemap.xml is static located on the webroot and accessible using https://site1.com/sitemap.xml

Now, we want to implement a multisite on the same instance and we need a new sitemap.xml for the new site. How can this be implemented and achieved. https://site2.com/sitemap.xml
This will give the static sitemap.xml for site2

We have a plan in future to make these dynamic as well.

We are currently on 10.1 and **not using SXA or Headless**

Answer (score 0):

You would need to give your sitemaps for each site different names. i.e. **sitemap-site1.xml** and **sitemap-site2.xml**.

In the past we have used the community built Dynamic Sitemap XML module (from Radoslaw Kozlowski) to help create our site.

You can find the Github repo (together with details about configuring multiple sitemaps for different sites) here:
https://github.com/ReoKzK/Sitecore.SharedSource.DynamicSitemap/wiki/Creating-new-sitemap-configuration

You will need to pull it and update the code to use the latest Sitecore Nuget packages.

Hope that helps.